# Modify an Arbitrary Number of Variables Within a Subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

So I have an application where I'm looking up data from a bunch of different tables and entering the data into a bunch of variables to be used elsewhere. I wrote a function to look up and return a row (as a Range) from a specified table given an entry in the first column:

```
Public Function RowLookup(table As Range, entry As String) As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Variant
    rowNum = Application.Match(entry, table.Columns.item(1), 0)

    If IsError(rowNum) Then
        RowLookup = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Else
        RowLookup = table.Rows(rowNum)(1)
    End If
End Function
```

However, now I've ended up with a ton of code that looks like this:

```
tempRow = RowLookup(Range("Table1"), var1)
If IsError(tempRow) Then
    var2 = ""
    var3 = ""
    var4 = ""
    var5 = ""
    Debug.Print "Error looking up data"
Else
    var2 = tempRow(1, 2)
    var3 = tempRow(1, 3)
    var4 = tempRow(1, 4)
    var5 = tempRow(1, 6)
End If
```

Any ideas on how to work this boilerplate code into the function? I want it to take an arbitrarily long list of (colIndex, variable) pairs and then set each variable based on columnIndex. Using a Collection doesn't seem to work as I can only change the entry in the Collection, not the original variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326429/vba-pass-array-by-reference-and-modify-contents might meet your needs though - pass in two arrays, one for column indexes and another with the corresponding variables you want to populate/clear.  Have your function return a Boolean to indicate match/no match.

Comment: Was trying something similar myself. Problem is that creating my own array and modifying that only changes the array, not the original variables. Solution by below seems to work, because I guess ParamArray creates an array of variables by reference? Very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the Vars and Table Index's as a [`ParamArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008927)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

I'd rework `RowLookup` as a Sub.  Param Arrayexpects pairs of Variables, and Table Column Numbers.

- An Odd number of passed parameters cauase an error.
- A Column Index > number of columns in Table is ignored
- Vars don't have to be Variants (they will be type cast, so could throw errors)

```
Public Sub RowLookup(table As Range, entry As Variant, ParamArray Vars() As Variant)
    Dim rowNum As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TableData As Variant
    Dim TableColumns As Long

    If WorksheetFunction.IsEven(UBound(Vars)) Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(Vars) - 1 Step 2
            Vars(i) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Next
    Else
        rowNum = Application.Match(entry, table.Columns(1), 0)

        If IsError(rowNum) Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(Vars) - 1 Step 2
                Vars(i) = CVErr(xlErrValue)
            Next
        Else
            TableData = table.Value
            TableColumns = UBound(TableData, 2)
            For i = 0 To UBound(Vars) - 1 Step 2
                If Vars(i + 1) >= 1 And Vars(i + 1) <= TableColumns Then
                    Vars(i) = TableData(rowNum, Vars(i + 1))
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and call it like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim SomeLongVar As Long
    Dim SomeStringVar As String
    Dim var3(1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim var4 As Variant
    Dim var5 As Variant

    var3(2) = 5 ' Column Index

    RowLookup Range("Table1"), "x", SomeLongVar, 2, SomeStringVar, 3, var3(1), var3(2)

    Debug.Print SomeLongVar, SomeStringVar, var3(1)
End Sub
```